# Shredding MySQL rows

Tags: mysql, posix

I know how to remove files in order to make them impossible to recover. But, how do I remove rows from a MySQL table in a POSIX environment in a way that leads to the same results? I'm currently rewriting all data with a nullified string with the same length as the original data before I proceed with deleting the row. Does it work? If not, how do I make it work?

Comment: Interesting question! I would however re-phrase to "Permanently remove mySQL rows" or "Shredding mySQL rows".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to do this in such a way that you can say with confidence that the original data is completely gone.

Take a look at this analysis which includes a case study of MySQL retention;

http://forensics.umass.edu/pubs/stahlberg07forensicDB.pdf

Comment: You've convinced me to never ever store anything sensitive in MySQL or to trust any service that does.